# Streaming from a Windows PC to a cellular phone

Tags: windows, video, streaming, cellular

What's the recommended method to stream video from my computer running Windows to my cellular phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [TVersity](http://tversity.com/).  It will stream music, photos and videos from your computer to any networked device. Usually the devices will see your computer as a media server and you would browse the selection. You can even use your device's built-in browser to access it (IE type the IP address of the computer that has the media on it in the browser and it will display the TVersity HTTP web server) to watch or listen to any file that is shared.

Comment: no problem...its always fun to listen or watch movies on a portable device with limited memory...like having your computer with you..thanks for the point and CHECK!!!